# pgAdmin3 not see database postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, import, pgadmin

I created DB with name "**food**" in command line in Linux Mint. I would like import dump to db, but I cant did it.

---

1. My pgAdmin didn't see this db. I try update list of db in pgAdmin, try reinstall pgAdmin, restart server.
2. I cant import dump to db in command line with help of official documentation command- "psql dbname < infile"([PostgreSQL Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/backup.html)). In general, I have to upload this dump([GeoNamesDB](https://github.com/x88/i18nGeoNamesDB))

### For example name of dump file- "_countries.sql".

What should I do, that my pgAdmin see db "**food**", and I can import dump to my database.

Comment: Are you sure you did create the db? What conmand did you use?

Comment: I use "createdb" command. Thanks for the help. I solved problem. I go to the file /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf and see that port in this file is 5433. I changed it to 5432. And my list of db in console=list of db in pgAdmin3. 
Now I should understand how upload _countries.sql to my db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use "createdb" command. Thanks for the help. I solved problem. I go to the file /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf and see that port in this file is 5433. I changed it to 5432. And my list of db in console=list of db in pgAdmin3. Now I should understand how upload _countries.sql to my db.
At finaly i understand what heppend.
When i installed postgresql at first, it installing bably. I reinstall it(postgresql), and when i found problem with ports(5432, 5433) i find lod version postgresql. In my computer was installen 2 postgresql.

If you find same problem check haw many postgresql intstallen in your computer.